# Cloning system nightmare with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, clone, acronis-trueimage

I am running Windows 8.1 that was initially a Windows 8 OEM from an ASUS Q501L laptop.

I first used Macrium Reflect and then Acronis True Image to fully clone my current hard drive onto an SSD. Both times it seemed to work. When swapping out the HDD for the SSD and trying to boot up, I get a blue screen with `inaccessible boot device`. I booted up into the Asus recovery partition, `refresh` results in an error, A*utomatic repair* results in an error (the disk is locked, please unlock the disk first) and `reset` doesn't seem like what I want to do so I haven't actually tried it. But I am quite sure it results in an error as well.

The point is, my SSD is bigger than the HDD I had, and I want to have that space available. So if I run `reset` i fear it might only give me the space that was available before.

The disk is not read-only. [I tried fixing the MBR master boot record](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows)

playing around with the bios setting `AHCPI` is not possible in my case, if I go to the BIOS, Advanced, SATA, and click on that option, my options are only AHCPI. There is nothing else I can select. I updated the BIOS to the newest version, the same thing.

[I tried downloading the Windows 8.1 install on a USB drive using the media installer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) it went to 97% in a 4 hours download, then I went away, when I came back it said "sorry something happened and we couldn't finish creating the flash drive restart the installer"

When I restart it, it takes 4 hours again. And I doubt restarting it and waiting will fix the error actually. There seems to be no file downloaded on the HD. The USB drive is *not* damaged.

I am disappointed about ASUS. I think all the problems are the result of the silly setup they provided with the manifold of existing rescue and whatnot partitions that make the disk too complex. Maybe the whole recovery thing was meant only for Windows 8, but not 8.1? go figure...

Since I am a developer I am not really looking forward to run Windows 10, but I guess a fresh install is the best way to go? Obviously I have, sadly, to pirate the windows now. I own Windows 8.1 and therefore Windows 10, right, but I can't get it to work due to stated problems.

I got the product key out and tried to download a Windows 8 version with it, with the error "This product key is not valid for a retail version of windows" obiosr something like that.

So back to pirating and a clean install, or is there something I am missing out?

*Edit:* I tried `reset` with the error : "a required partition is missing"
obviously the SSD works when connected via USB. Might there actually be a problem of my computer reading it when in the SATA slot? The BIOS recognizes the my crucial...

Comment: How do you get to the conclusion you have to pirate software, if you upgrade to Windows 10 on that device once, then it will automatically activated in the future.

Comment: The HDD is fine tho, right? Maybe try another backup product? I've had good luck with macrium (which I still use with XP) and Veem endpoint backup (which I've used to finesse a recovery to a smaller drive by shrinking my system partition and restoring paritions one by one).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I am using my HDD right now... since I cannot use the SDD right? Try a THIRD backup product? really? no... I already tried 2.

Comment: @Ramhound ok, please give me the information on how I can upgrade to windows 10 on a device that DOES NOT BOOT UP. The only way to solve my problem is doing a clean fresh install. How do I do a clean fresh install? Windows was preinstalled, there is no installer disc.

Comment: There are lots of sources for a Windows 8.1 .iSO, which would be needed, if you ended up installing a pirated copy.  So I would use that .ISO and install Windows 8.1, the key will automatically be detected, then you can upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: The _silly setup_ you are seeing is **not** specific to ASUS, if you are seeing 7 partitions (OEM+ESP+MSR+Reco8+Windows+Reco8.1+Factory_image) I believe this is the standard state of affairs for OEM computer shipped with 8 and updated to 8.1, where Win8.1 (not ASUS) did add the recovery partition after Windows; and yes it has to do with being able to restore the device to factory condition (running 8, the only thing you can legally sell the license to); and I guess the new policy with Win10 (restoring from last downloaded image, not the factory one) has to do with that complexity...

Comment: Are you sure you cloned **all** the partitions needed to boot; for instance, have you run `bcdedit /enum all` and checked that any volume listed has been cloned to the SSD? I am guessing that the recovery partition (with WinRE.WIM) is needed to adjust the reference to the drives within the BCD on the SSD, and it is located on a partition which is not present on the SSD, so it fails.

Comment: I cloned the entire disk 3 times. It would be a big surprise if it wouldn't have cloned all partitions of the disk, 3 times, with 3 different programs. Don't you think?

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem and I've struggled a lot before using the only piece of software that worked for me: Minitool Partition Wizard.

Just clone your HD to SSD and follow the wizard, check out the partition size on the SSD before applying changes and that's it.

Comment: so you cloned your drive with it?

Comment: that didn't work.